# How do I change file permissions on /tmp during and elastic beanstalk app deploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ami

I have a elastic beanstalk webapp running tomcat8.5 on a Amazon linux 2 AMI. My webapp launches a headless chrome image via chromedriver to perform some functions. The healess chrome process needs to be able to write to /tmp to unpack some stuff on startup and if it cant write to /tmp it fails. In my .ebextensions I have tried using

```
 535_permission:
    command: sudo chmod 777 /tmp
```

which according to my cfn-init-cmd.log excutes fine. However is I do do an ls -al on /tmp it has the default permissions of

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 ec2-user root      334 Oct 18 10:54 .
```

If I issue the command manually it works. I do not understand why the commands runs ok in eb config but hasnt applied when I manuall inspect the filesystem. I am not sure if /tmp gets reset after the ebextensions run, and maybe I need to run it later somehow.

Comment: Usually, apps can write to /tmp. Does you application get access denied?

Comment: Yes. If I change permission on /tmp to 777 or if I do sudo chorn tomcat:tomcat /tmp then it works fine.

Comment: `535_permission` is in `commands` or `container_commands`? I will try reproduce.

Comment: its in commands:

Comment: I already checked, and by default permissions on `/tmp` are `drwxrwxrwt`, at least on python EB environment.

Comment: I also checked on `Tomcat 8.5 with Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/4.1.2` now using sample EB app - permissions in `/tmp/` are also `drwxrwxrwt` by default. Thus, I'm not sure why would you get different ones?

Comment: Thanks so much for looking. I had some old code that was messing with /tmp perms that I thought I'd removed.In my defense I wrote that fragment  5 years ago and forgot it was there.  When I removed that it behaves as youve described.

Comment: No problem. If you don't mind, I will provide an answer for future reference:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

By default, `/tmp` on EB environments has **permissions 777** (i.e. `drwxrwxrwt`). Subsequently, all applications can write to it and normally no changes are required.

However, the OP's issue was caused by using a **legacy code** version which was changing the permissions, so that new code was not able to use the `/tmp`.

The **solution** was to remove the legacy code.